# How to configure Web server(IIS) and App Server(.Net) in two different physically separated machine

Tags: asp.net, iis, server, webserver, appserver

[Image of N-tier Architecture i need to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRi9V.png)

I would like to know what are the server configuration for the web server and app server if both of them located in two different Machine?

Client Request is to Changing the current server architecture from

client <---> (Web Server/App Server) <---> Database

TO

client <--->  Web Server(IIS) <---> App Server(.net) <---> Database

In this scenario, the Web server (which contains the presentation layer logic) is physically separated from the application server that implements the business logic.

Why i need to achieve this because of following reasons:

- Security requirements dictate that business logic cannot be deployed to the perimeter network.
- Application code that makes heavy use of resources on the server, and want to offload that functionality to another server.

Any possible links or resources for guidance would be very helpful.

I have searched the web for two days regarding this i have gone through all the theory part of it but none i found regarding to the server configuration.

Comment: IIS is both the web server and app server for .NET Framework apps. So it is rather confusing what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I understand thus I have edited the question to give more clarity. I understand that .net framework consist of both Web server and App Server  in IIS. But is there any way in which i can change the configuration so that i can achieve app server in one physical machine and web server in another? Hope i helped to give more clarity on my question.

Answer (score 0):

As Lex says the IIS is both the web server and app server for .NET Framework apps. We could understand clearly about what you want to ask for us.

Do you mean you want to use IIS to redirect the request to another server which is used the self-host asp.net application?

If this is your requirement, I suggest you could consider using ARR reverse proxy to achieve your requirement. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

Comment: As we know that the IIS Server is both the web server and App server for .NET Framework. What I want to achieve is to separate application server and web server and place them in two different machine.  The Web server (which contains the presentation layer logic) want to physically separated from the application server which implements the business logic.